# The number of MiniBatchSize always 1 even when i change it in minibatchqueue parameters to 32? in MATLAB

Tags: deep-learning

**I follow the example in Matlab for CNN with Multiple Outputs**

Train Network with Multiple Outputs

https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/train-network-with-multiple-outputs.html

**But with a colour image as** input data with two output as below:

Name          Size                        Bytes  Class     Attributes
XTrain      128x128x3x2016            792723456  double
Name              Size              Bytes  Class          Attributes
yTrain1      1x2016             2230  categorical
Name              Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
yTrain2      1x2016            16128  double

I define **minibatchqueue** object as below:

```
mbq = minibatchqueue(dsTrain,...
    'MiniBatchSize',32,...
    'MiniBatchFcn', @preprocessData,...
    'MiniBatchFormat',{'SSCB','',''});
```

**But the number of Batch size in output is always 1 as**

```
mbq = 
minibatchqueue with 3 outputs and properties:
Mini-batch creation:
MiniBatchSize: 1
PartialMiniBatch: 'return'
MiniBatchFcn: @preprocessDataJwan
DispatchInBackground: 0
Outputs:
OutputCast: {'single'  'single'  'single'}
OutputAsDlarray: [1 1 1]
MiniBatchFormat: {'SSCB'  ''  ''}
OutputEnvironment: {'auto'  'auto'  'auto'}
```

even I check the data size

```
[dlX,dlY1,dlY2] = next(mbq);
         size(dlX)
         size(dlY1)
         size(dlY2)
```

ans =
128         128           3        2016

ans =
2        2016

ans =
1        2016

please, can anyone help me with that?